# Passport control and Schengen visa doubt

Tags: customs-and-immigration, lufthansa, munich, frankfurt, zurich

My flight from Bangalore to Amsterdam via Frankfurt has been cancelled and I have been given an alternate flight:

Option 1: Take a different Swiss Air flight on the same day but via Zurich Airport.

Concern: As per my visa application, my first point of entry in the Schengen area is Germany; will it be an issue if I enter via Zurich, Switzerland?

Option 2: Take a flight to Amsterdam via Munich but with only one hour and five minutes of transfer time.

Concern: Is the short one hour time sufficient for passport control and boarding?

Option 3: Take the same flight to Munich but with a one hour and twenty-five minute transfer time, and then a layover at Frankfurt for one hour and twenty-five minutes before the flight to Amsterdam.

Concern: Do I need to go through passport control again at Frankfurt to board the Amsterdam flight? Will my active Schengen tourism visa be valid for this transfer?

Comment: All 3 countries are inside the Schengen Area. Immigration Control will be at the first port of entry. Where the first point of entry is is not important. Important is only that your main destination (where you will be staying the longest) remains as stated in your application.

Answer (score 4):

With a Schengen visa, you are allowed to *adjust* your itinerary *after* the visa has been issued, as long as the premise of the trip remains the same and as long as you stay within the validity and duration. There are a few exceptions, with a limited territorial validity, but that would be printed on the visa and it is rather uncommon.

Of course you are not allowed to *misrepresent* your itinerary *during* the application. But what you describe here sounds like a perfect example of *adjusting* the itinerary with the same premise. You would still go to Amsterdam, only through a different hub. Changes in the itinerary can be problematic if they would change which consulate you need to apply to, but I presume you got your visa from the Netherlands, not from Germany.

The immigration control will be when you first enter the Schengen area and switch from an international flight to one within Schengen, in Zurich or in Munich. There will probably a security/identity control when you board the next flight(s), but not an immigration control.